# How to split a string between two character into sub groups in R

Tags: regex, r, matrix, split, extract

I have a list of codes in the second column of a table and I want to extract some elements of each code then store them in new columns associated with each of the codes. 
Each code consists of letters followed by some numbers. The letters are P, F, I , R, C repeated with the same order in all codes but the number of digits are varying in each code.

For example: consider the codes as below:

```
P1F2I235R15C145   P1   F2   I23   R15   C145
P24F1I12R124C96   P24  F1   I12   R124  C96
```

so in this way I can split each code into its constitutes sub-codes, and store these components into new columns in the same table.
thanks

Comment: If the letters are always repeated in the same order, then isn't there high redundancy in your data? Why don't you use those as column names instead?

Comment: The sub codes are actually variables values (with categorical codes) so I need them to be stored in front of each original code as it is requested. all the values started with P are measures related to variable P and all the values after F are measures for the same individual related to variable F and so on.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a possible `stringi` solution

```
library(stringi)
x <- c("P1F2I235R15C145","P24F1I12R124C96")
res <- stri_split_regex(x,"(?=([A-Za-z]=?))",perl = TRUE,simplify = TRUE,omit_empty = TRUE)
cbind.data.frame(x, res)
#                 x   1  2    3    4    5
# 1 P1F2I235R15C145  P1 F2 I235  R15 C145
# 2 P24F1I12R124C96 P24 F1  I12 R124  C96
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
#simulate your data frame
df<-data.frame(code=c("P1F2I235R15C145","P24F1I12R124C96"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
#split the columns
cbind(df,do.call(rbind,regmatches(df$code,gregexpr("[PFIRC][0-9]+",df$code))))
#             code   1  2    3    4    5
#1 P1F2I235R15C145  P1 F2 I235  R15 C145
#2 P24F1I12R124C96 P24 F1  I12 R124  C96
```

What @AnandaMatho suggested in the comment was to let the letter in front of the code go away and name the columns accordingly. Something like that:

```
res<-cbind(df,do.call(rbind,regmatches(df$code,gregexpr("(?<=[PFIRC])[0-9]+",df$code,perl=TRUE))))
names(res)<-c("Code","P","F","I","R","C")
#             Code  P F   I   R   C
#1 P1F2I235R15C145  1 2 235  15 145
#2 P24F1I12R124C96 24 1  12 124  96
```

Comment: Both options are nice Nicola. +1 :-)

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)
dt<-data.table(code=c("P1F2I235R15C145","P24F1I12R124C96"))
dt[,c("P","F","I","R","C"):=
     lapply(c("P","F","I","R","C"),
            function(x)regmatches(code,regexpr(paste0(x,"[0-9]+"),code)))]

> dt
              code   P  F    I    R    C
1: P1F2I235R15C145  P1 F2 I235  R15 C145
2: P24F1I12R124C96 P24 F1  I12 R124  C96
```

And if you do end up deciding to drop the letters from the front, a minor adjustment:

```
dt[,c("P","F","I","R","C"):=
     lapply(c("P","F","I","R","C"),
            function(x)regmatches(code,regexpr(paste0("(?<=",x,")[0-9]+"),
                                               code,perl=T)))]
> dt
              code  P F   I   R   C
1: P1F2I235R15C145  1 2 235  15 145
2: P24F1I12R124C96 24 1  12 124  96
```

---

Or using devel version of `data.table (v1.9.5+)`:

```
dt[, c("P", "F", "I", "R", "C") := 
      tstrsplit(code, "(?<=.)(?=[[:alpha:]][0-9]+)", perl=TRUE)]
#               code   P  F    I    R    C
# 1: P1F2I235R15C145  P1 F2 I235  R15 C145
# 2: P24F1I12R124C96 P24 F1  I12 R124  C96
```

Comment: Thanks @Arun for what seems like the perfect `data.table` solution for this problem, given the format of `code` is regular it makes perfect sense to use `tstrsplit`; @Arun can you think of an easy adjustment that would split out just the numbers and not the letters?.